# "Finite" and "infinite": another example?

Tags: pronunciation

*Finite* and *infinite* come from the same root word, but the prefix of the latter completely changes the pronunciation. Speaking English as a second-language and reading a lot more than I listen, it makes me nervous that I might be missing other such changes.

Is this an isolated occurrence?

Comment: I haven't checked out the whole list, but a brief skim [here](http://dictionary.kids.net.au/wordsstartingwith/In) didn't throw up anything else)

Comment: related: [Pronunciation differences between finite and infinite](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8218/pronunciation-differences-between-finite-and-infinite)

Comment: @Andy: I saw that one, but found no additional examples.

Comment: No, you're right, I skimmed through as well and couldn't find any other examples. I just wanted to suggest it as related reading.

Comment: You may also like to note that a number of words change pronunciation depending on whether used as a noun or a verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you are looking for examples of words that change pronunciation because of prefixes. Another example would be famous (ˈfā-məs) and infamous (ˈin-fə-məs).

I don't know what this phenomenon is called, but it can also apply to other derivations from the same word; for instance, house (haʊs) and houses (ˈhaʊzɪz), (or the verb house (haʊz)), photograph (ˈfō-tə-ˌgraf) and photographer (fə-ˈtä-grə-fər).

Answer (score 1):

Another example of word that changes pronunciation because a prefix is *belief*, which is pronounced /bəˈlif/ or /biˈlif/ in American English, and where the prefix *un-* changes the pronunciation to /ˌənbəˈlif/.

Comment: I thought it was /bəˈliːf/ in AmE and /bɪˈliːf/ in BrE.

Comment: The pronunciations I reported are the ones NOAD reports as American English pronunciations.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the prefix *didn't* change the pronunciation.
The pronunciation for infinite was the original form (coming from French/Latin).
Somehow, when the prefix was removed, the pronunciation changed.