# Why doesn't the silent "e" work on "infinite"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels, silent-letters

Why doesn't the silent "e" work on the word "infinite"?

What I mean is, why does mate have a long "a", but infinite has a short "i"?

Comment: It is silent. When it's not silent it's spelled infinity. Maybe someone smarter than I am can say why.

Comment: Nice question!  It never occurred to me wonder why "fye-nite" but not "in-fye-nite".  I am looking forward to answers to this question.

Comment: @user814064, normally a terminal silent "e" causes the previous vowell to be pronounced long, but here it is pronounced short.  For example: Fat vs Fate.  Bit vs Bite.  That's what he's asking: why not a long "i" here with the silent "e" on the end.

Comment: It's not the only example: _opposite_ (but not _apposite_), _favourite_, _definite_, and most words in _-ive_, show the same pattern. I don't know why.

Comment: @ColinFine Stress.

Comment: It may be because ifinite is coming from Infinity?

Comment: @Nirock It’s because you’re trying to read something into English spelling that isn’t there. English spelling represents the pronunciation of Middle English, not of Modern English. There is no connection between English spelling and pronunciation. You just have to learn them all.

Comment: @tchrist ? The four words I mentioned, one of which does not follow this pattern, all have the same stress pattern, as do _parasite_ and _plebiscite_. Having said that, I observe that those four words were all originally adjectives, and I can't think of many other adjectives in _-ite_.

Comment: @ColinFine *Erudite, impolite, composite, recondite, exquisite, petite, requisite, tripartite, heteroclite, preterite, trite*.  Yeah, there aren’t many, and they aren’t all the same.

Comment: Aren't *all* the words *emphasized* so far Latin derivatives (regardless of their moving into / through Middle English to the present) ?  I noticed some years ago that the words I had the most trouble spelling correctly were due to Caesar and all his pals - C*ae*ser ? Gads, I think I'm gonna have a seizure - or maybe have a cow via a Caesarean !

Comment: @HowardPautz Don’t blame Caesar, who pronounced his name exactly as it’s spelled. Latin was very simple in that regard.  English, not so much.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist ~ fat with a long vowel would be fart, not fate. Bit with a long vowel would be beat, not bite.

Comment: @Nirock ~ it 'doesn't work' because infinite is an inflected word - in+finite. In the bare form *finite* it 'works', but in the same way as the second 'o' in photograph changes when it becomes photography, the ''i in finite changes when it become infinite.

Comment: @RoaringFish: no, that argument doesn't work either, as it doesn't account for _opposite_, _favourite_ or others mentioned by tchrist.

Comment: There's an interesting discussion of the same topic earlier on this:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8218/pronunciation-differences-between-finite-and-infinite.  The argument there is that the dactyl form is easier to pronounce, hence the shortened vowel.   Not totally sure I buy that, but it's interesting.  What say you, good Mr. @tchrist?

Answer (score 1):

As @tchrist has pointed out with excellent examples, the final e's ability to create a long vowel sound is a 'tendency' and not a 'rule'.

The specific reason why 'infinite' is pronounced as it is has been discussed here:
[Pronunciation differences between "finite" and "infinite"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8218/pronunciation-differences-between-finite-and-infinite)

It boils down to where stresses occur in English speech. The link above provides far more precise explanation than I'm capable of.

Edit: also see Brian Hooper's answer: ["Finite" and "infinite": another example?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/finite-and-infinite-another-example?lq=1) for more examples of how an additional syllable can completely change pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

The apparently irregular pronunciation of *infinite* (that it is not `ɪnˈfaɪnaɪt` or `ˈɪnfənaɪt`) is a confluence of two factors, both historical, I think.

The first is that the negative prefix *in-* (and its kin, *il-*, *im-*, ...) is only rarely stressed in English.  In most cases where it is, there has either been semantic drift between the prefixed and unprefixed forms (*impotent* is not quite the negation of *potent*; likewise for *infamous* and *famous*, and *invalid* [`ˈɪnvəlɪd`] and *valid*); or else the unprefixed form is simply unattested (*impudent*, *indigent*, *indolent*, *insolent*).  Semantically transparent examples like *infinite* and *finite*, or *indirect* and *direct*, are in the minority.  This suggests that the process that drew stress onto the *in-* prefix was an archaic one, possibly one that operated in the language from which English borrowed the words in question (e.g., Old French).

The second is that pronunciation of *-finite* as `fənət` occurs, I think, only in *infinite* and *definite* (and derivatives, like *indefinite*).  Again, this contrasts with the pronunciation `faɪnaɪt`, which occurs in *cofinite*, *subfinite*, and *transfinite*.  Given that the latter are all modern innovations, this suggests that the pronunciation `fənət`, too, may be a relic from earlier phonological processes, possibly active in the source language from which English borrowed these words.

So, the pronunciation of *infinite* is doubly archaic—which may be the most principled account one can give of this particular oddity of English spelling.

---

BTW, I know that many people have a higher vowel than schwa in `-fənət`, but I’m following my own (native) pronunciation here.  Also, I’ve deliberately omitted secondary stress.  *Definite* may have come to English straight from Latin (in about the 16th century), but its stress and vowel quality may have analogised with *infinite*.